# PHP long script - "Aborted" status

Tags: php, apache, abort

I have a php script which connects to the SFTP server, downloads files (book covers) from the specific directory, copies images to my server and update information about books in my database (set path to cover image).

For working with SFTP I use Net_SFTP class.

When I run this script for SFTP server which contains about 7000 images, eventually I receive "Aborted" status. After nearly 10-14 minutes of execution script stops.

I can not find any error message in the site log file (where we write all warning, critical errors etc). My question is in what file I can find mention of this error? Is it possible that script has been aborted without writing details to any log file? We have Apache on the CentOS.

P.S. Already increased "max_execution_time" parameter to 3600. Didn't help.

**UPD**

I tried

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

in the beginning of the script. No luck.

**UPD 2**

I don't always see "Aborted" status. Usually browser shows loading indicator while scrip has already stopped (aborted?) on the server. Any ideas why it can happen?

Answer (score 0):

use

> set_time_limit(0);

at the top of your script, so that the script will run forever - however this is not recommended and your web server might catch you out with an imposed HTTP timeout (usually around 5 minutes).

You should check your web server's guides for more information about HTTP timeouts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ok, so if it's timeout problem, where I can find error details about it? In what log files?

Comment: you can use in your code error_reporting(E_ALL); normally you will see a timeout message

Comment: Tried error_reporting(E_ALL) - still do not see any error message in apache log or in the site log.

Comment: @Tamara you got some advance?

Comment: yes, I've found out what was the problem. Apparently script was not aborted, it entered endless loop and that's why I saw loading indicator in browser. I'm not sure why I saw "Aborted" status several times... Additional details can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639927/phpseclib-endless-downloading   Thanks for interest in my problem