# phpseclib - endless downloading

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib 0.3.1 for working with remote SFTP server. I have a script which downloads cover images from the SFTP, save them on my server and make updates in database.

I run this script  for 7000 images and after nearly 10-12 minutes, it looks like script has stopped (but eventually I have found out that script entered an endless loop)

After some investigation, I have found the following details:

1. function `get($remote_file, $local_file = false)` from SFTP.php is called for downloading image file
2. In this function `_get_sftp_packet()` is called in while(true) loop.
3. In _get_sftp_packet() there is a call of `_get_channel_packet(NET_SFTP_CHANNEL);`
4. And in _get_channel_packet() there is a call of `$response = $this->_get_binary_packet();`

My problem that this $response is empty string. In function `_get_sftp_packet()` length of this response is used as a decrement and if function returns empty string (or length 0) - I will never get out of the loop in `_get_sftp_packet()`

Did anyone face this problem? What empty response means for `_get_binary_packet()` function?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an issue with the window size handling. An issue that has been fixed for a while now.

You're running 0.3.1? The latest version is 0.3.10. You're like 5 versions behind.

Comment: You were right, after updating to version 0.3.10 bug disappeared.